# CPQ behavior for Products

Tags: reporting, cpq, product

I just joined a company that has been having some issues with CPQ for quite some time now.
Most of the issues are related on how CPQ was set up, and that they can't report on the products they have sold...

I have been trying to pull the data from the report type **Opportunities with Products** which to my knowledge, are products attached to the Opportunity. To my surprise, they are non existent, meaning that most of the products are just inside the QuoteLine that lives in the Quote and no where to be found in the Opportunity.

Is this CPQ expected behavior? Meaning, that once you start using CPQ, the products you use does not get attached to the opportunity?

If that is the case, how would I be able to report on these products, but also to include the Opportunities.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sf_cpq/sf_cpq_learn_quotes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Products associated with the Opportunity from the Salesforce CPQ Quote, can be reported on from the Opportunities with Products report type.

The Report Type is pulling together the Opportunity and Opportunity Products (otherwise known as OpportunityLineItem) objects.

In the UI it is abstracted with the naming convention being Opportunities and Opportunity Products.

But through the API for example, you could report on OpportunityLineItem and Opportunity to find the products associated with the Opportunity from the Quote.

In case it might be helpful, here's some documentation on the field mapping between Quote and Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312879